# Free app to generate random picture collages

Tags: gratis, windows-7, image-processing, collage

I am looking for an app to create a pictures collage.
It should be generated automatically with settings like

- final image size
- distance between pictures
- number of pictures
- directory to take the pictures from

The app would randomly make some pictures big and others small to create an "artistic" random collage effect.

Example of a grid collage:

[image: Example grid collage]

Requirements:

- Works on Windows 7
- Free, ideally open source
- Input format: JPG at least
- Output format: JPG

If nothing better is available, C# code (WPF / WForms) to start from and some algorithms for that are good aswell.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Input format (also only JPEG, or should it be able to read multiple formats – and if so, which)? How shall it work: selecting images manually, scanning a given directory (or multiple of them/incl. sub-directories)? Final size configurable? Intended workflow? Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Though your question might look really intuitive, it's the details making the difference :)

Comment: You want it to create that automatically, right? How to decide which images become small and which are large? Just random? How to choose between different layouts? What input file formats must be supported? What is the intended usage? Do you want to print it or just use digital?

Comment: @ThomasWeller Do you have a program in mind that fulfils my criteria?

Comment: I did not understand your criteria yet, since there are many open questions. You could do it with Inkscape for example, but I guess that's not what you want

Comment: @ThomasWeller aktualisiert.

Comment: @VitalisHommel still lacks several details requested in above comments: how are images selected? Intended workflow? Input file formats? How to decide which images become small and which are large? Intended usage?

Comment: @Izzy I am sure that the selection of available software is so limited that you take what you can get. More details are leading to a "not available".

Comment: You could mark them as "nice to have" – so they wouldn't lead to "not available", but still give a more clear picture of what you're (ideally) after. Up to you – but the better you describe what you want, the better recommendations can match it.

Comment: @Izzy No, actually. By giving more details it just limits the answers in a way that I don't want.

Answer (score 4):

[Image Magick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) which includes a Montage command line tool with a huge number of [options](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/montage/#montage), can produce grid montage for you and it is possible to either resize all of the images to a single size or allow spacing around them.  Where you wish to combine smaller images into one cell you can do so by using it iteratively.